# Create Json in VB.net from string and use it in WebRequest

Tags: json, vb.net, rest, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to call [openrouteservice api](https://openrouteservice.org/) in vb.net and therefore tried to follow the [documentation/examples](https://openrouteservice.org/dev/#/api-docs/v2/directions/%7Bprofile%7D/gpx/post). The example shows below code as working example:

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim request = TryCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car/gpx"), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)

    request.Method = "POST"

    request.Accept = "application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8"
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "xxxxMYKEYxxxx")
    request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")

    Using writer = New System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes({"coordinates:[[8.681495,49.41461],[8.686507,49.41943],[8.687872,49.420318]]"})
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        writer.Write(byteArray)
        writer.Close()
    End Using
    Dim responseContent As String
    Using response = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        Using reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd()
            Console.WriteLine(responseContent.ToString())
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

The example shows that the content of the request body should be the following:

```
{"coordinates":[[8.681495,49.41461],[8.686507,49.41943],[8.687872,49.420318]]}
```

But when running the example i get the following error:

```
'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.'
```

So i figured that the request fails because of the invalid Json.
My question is how to create a JSON resulting in the same as in the example-JSON provided above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API is expecting a JSON object, representing an array of arrays of double values, as the content of the HttpRequest, encoded as an UTF-8 string, sent as a byte array.

This collection can be represented by a `List(Of List(Of Double)` Property Type of a .Net class:

```vbnet
' Note that JavaScriptSrializer might ignore <JsonProperty>,
' so use lower case, since the Web API is case-sensitive
Friend Class MyObject
    <JsonProperty("coordinates")>
    Public Property coordinates As List(Of List(Of Double))
End Class
```

After this, we just need to fill the List:

```vbnet
Dim myobj = New MyObject() With {
    .Coordinates = New List(Of List(Of Double)) From {
        New List(Of Double)({8.681495, 49.41461}),
        New List(Of Double)({8.686507, 49.41943}),
        New List(Of Double)({8.687872, 49.420318})
    }
}
```

And serialize it, with either [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (install the NuGet package via NuGet Package Manager) or [JavaScriptSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer) (or any other JSON serializer available):

`JavaScriptSerializer` requires a Project reference to `System.Web.Extension` and to import `System.Web.Script.Serialization`.

```vbnet
' Using Json.Net
Dim Json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobj)

' Or JavaScriptSerializer
Dim json = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myobj)
```

► The original code has more than one issue:

- The **`webRequest.ContentLength`** is set too late: it needs to be set before the request sent
- The StreamWriter used to write to the WebRequest Stream will compromise the process: it's not needed and it will be closed before the bytes are written to the Request Stream
- `Content-Type` cannot be set using the Headers, we must use **`WebRequest.ContentType`** property
- Added **`SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`** in case this code is used in Windows 7 or a WM (in Windows 7, the default is `SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls`, thus TLS1.0, which isn't really used anymore, TLS1.2 is (still) the major player at this time)

Fixed original code, using `JavaScriptSerializer` to serialize the request data:

Replace **`Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization`** with **`Imports Newtonsoft.Json`** if you use Json.Net.

```vbnet
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Dim myobj = New MyObject() With {
    .Coordinates = New List(Of List(Of Double)) From {
        New List(Of Double)({8.681495, 49.41461}),
        New List(Of Double)({8.686507, 49.41943}),
        New List(Of Double)({8.687872, 49.420318})
    }
}

Dim json As String = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myobj)

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
Dim request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car/gpx")

request.Method = "POST"
request.PreAuthenticate = True
request.Accept = "application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8"
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "[Your API Key]")
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Dim jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)
request.ContentLength = jsonBytes.Length
Using reqStream = request.GetRequestStream()
    reqStream.Write(jsonBytes, 0, jsonBytes.Length)
End Using

Dim responseContent As String = String.Empty
Using response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse),
    responseStream = response.GetResponseStream(),
    reader = New StreamReader(responseStream)
    responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

Comment: just checked again, this gives me an exception when calling `request.getResponse`: 
`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.IO.IOException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response.`

Comment: Yes, there's more than one mistake in your original code. I didn't fix the errors because I focused on the JSON generation. I have now posted the whole request, with all the errors fixed. See the added note about JavaScriptSerializer. If you can use Json.Net instead, better. But this code will work anyway.

Comment: This did the job, thank you very much! Where did you know the security protocol from?

Comment: If you mean `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`, I added this because, if you're using Window 7 (or your code might end up there), the default SSL protocol there is `SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls`, so there's a very good chance that the request will be refused (this API uses HTTPS, quite improbable it accepts `TLS1.0`). Also, the `WebRequest.ContentType` cannot be set using the Headers (for *mysterious* reasons) and you were writing to the wrong Stream + minor changes.